# One of the best ways to numerically integrate a signal?

Tags: position, integration

I need to get position $x$ (integration) from velocity $v$. One could use 1st order Euler integration as

$x_{t+1} = x_t + \Delta v_t$

However, doing so leads to errors proportional to sampling time delta. 
Do you know any more accurate solution please?

Comment: I assume that you want to solve a first order differential equation: Runge-Kutta. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method

Comment: But Runge-Kutta requires an explicit knowledge of the function $f$, which is it not met in my scenario. We have only measures of velocity: $v_0$, $v_1$... $v_t$

Comment: Simpson' rule then. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson.27s_rule

Comment: You will definitely find this book useful (best literature ever) - [Burden - Numerical Analysis](http://ins.sjtu.edu.cn/people/mtang/textbook.pdf), Chapter 4.